# The multi-part identifier "System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputText" could not be bound

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, sqlcommand

I have an insert sql statement that uses the SqlCommand functionality for sql injection prevention, but it gives the error: The multi-part identifier "System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputText" could not be bound. I use the same SqlCommand functionality for updating the same table with no problems, however, this simple insert below gives the error. Can anyone help?

```
sSql = "INSERT INTO [camss].[dbo].[tb_ds0402req] ( [ds0402_key] ,[lname] ) " +
       "VALUES (" + Session["DS0402Key"] + "," + @VisitorLName + ");";

try
{ 
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sSql, conn))
    {
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VisitorLName", VisitorLName.Value);
     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}

catch (Exception ex)
{
//error handling code
}
```

Comment: The way that `sSql` is built appears vulnerable to SQL Injection.  Have you considered that [Bobby Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/) could be one of your users?

Comment: Prepared statements don't help but so much unless you put every variable value into a parameter.  In this case, for example, you'd say `VALUES(@DS0402Key, @VisitorLName)`, and add a parameter `@DS0402Key` to the command the same way you have `@VisitorLName`.

Answer (score 2):

If it is indeed this code that's throwing the error, my guess would be that because your escaping and quoting are all jacked up, you end up with a query like

```
INSERT INTO [camss].[dbo].[tb_ds0402req] ( [ds0402_key] ,[lname] ) 
VALUES (whatever your key is unquoted!, System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputText)
```

(assuming `VisitorLName` is an `HtmlInputText` control).  You're not adding the string `"@VisitorLName"`, cause it's not in quotes -- you're inserting the return value from `VisitorLName.ToString()`...which, AFAIK, returns the fully-qualified name of the type of the control.

(You're not getting an error while catting `@VisitorLName` without quotes, because `@` is C#'s way of escaping identifiers so that you can use keywords as variable names and such.  As far as C# cares, you just said ...`+ VisitorLName +`... .)

Note also that the way you're building the SQL string, you're not taking advantage of parameters, which are the main feature that would prevent SQL injection -- and simplify your SQL building, to boot!  If you're going to use parameters, use them for every value that's not meant to be a table name or whatever.  (For table/database/schema/etc names, you're on your own.  You can't use parameters to stand in for those.  Read: you're vulnerable to SQL injection again.  So don't do that unless you have to!)

In order to fix the problem, change your code so that it reads something like

```
sSql = "INSERT INTO [camss].[dbo].[tb_ds0402req] ( [ds0402_key] ,[lname] ) " +
       "VALUES (@DS0402Key, @VisitorLName)";

try
{ 
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sSql, conn))
    {
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DS0402Key", Session["DS0402Key"]);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VisitorLName", VisitorLName.Value);
     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
//error handling code
}
```

Also, find where you're sticking the key into the session...and make sure you're not inserting a whole control (rather than just its value).

Comment: Thank you for your response, all good suggestions.  I tried adding the Session["DS0402Key"] as a parameter and when I reference it in the insert sql, VS2010 gives an error that it does not exist in the current context.  I tried hardcoding the value of the DS0402Key along with @VisitorLName in the sql and I still receive the original error.

Comment: I also removed the DS0402Key colunm entirely just to rule out that it may be causing the problem but I still receive the original error.

Comment: It's not just the added parameter that's different above.  Note the SQL string (in particular, that i'm not building it ad-hoc by catting stuff together; i'm letting the parameters do the work).  The way you were doing stuff, everything's quoted all wrong.  That's where your error is more than likely coming from.

Comment: I hear what you're saying and it's a practice that I'll use going forward, but the original error still occurs when I use an insert statement with one column as in: 
sSql = "INSERT INTO [camss].[dbo].[tb_ds0402req] ( [lname] ) VALUES (@VisitorLName)";

Comment: Then the changes i've suggested probably aren't made correctly.  If you could add your code (as it exists now, "fixed", but still breaking) on to your answer (*add* it; don't replace what's there!), or put it in a pastebin and link it, i could help more.  But at this point, i have to assume the error lies elsewhere.  The code as i've written it should work just fine.

Comment: Your right.  I went through the code more carefully and it's working the way you suggested.  Thank you so much for your help.